# The command line output should be updated to a file at the specific line

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file at the location ~/Desktop/test/dummy.txt with the below text

```
[client]
clientName = 

[servername]
testserver-1
```

The dummy.txt file should get updated with the output of `hostname -s` at the end of “clientName = “ line

Comment: so what did you try? Please check [ask].

Comment: Not that it matters, but... That config file makes no sense. Why is there a `[servername]` section? Why is `testserver-1` on a line on its own? So many questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to append the result of the command `hostname -s` in your `dummy.txt` file, you can try this:

```
awk -v hostname="$(hostname -s)" '$1=="clientName" {$3=hostname}1' dummy.txt
```

It passes the hostname as a variable and append it when the string `clientName` is found.

---

You can also use `sed` to do the same:

```
sed "/^clientName/s/$/ $(hostname -s)/" dummy.txt
```

`/^clientName/` is the search pattern for which the subsitution `s` will apply. The substitution appends the result of the shell command `$(hostname -s)`at end of the line (`$`)

Comment: It worked, Is it possible using sed command?

Comment: How does {$3=hostname}1 work? Can you elaborate?

Comment: `hostname` is the variable set with `-v` option. `1` is a shortcut for the default action in awk, meaning `{print}` (print the whole line)

Comment: -bash-4.1$ cat testfile

[deployment-client]

clientName = 

[target-broker:deploymentServer]

targetUri = 

In continuation to the current question.

With the following command I'm able to update the clientName and how can i update targetUri=example.com along with the clientName in one shot?

awk -v hostname="$(hostname -s)" '$1=="clientName" {$3=hostname}1' deploymentclient.conf

Comment: @Sai Please describe your new issue in a separate question (as comments are not suited for changing the scope of the question)